# How to send c++ lists via sockets to a remote server and write those info to a file using PHP

Tags: php, c++, sockets

I want to achieve the following:

- send the data from the above C++ source to a PHP script (that I create) on a remote server via **sockets** (can be wether WinHTTP or regular sockets, **no** curl or other 3rd party libraries)
- the PHP will parse all the data and write it to a file. There can be multiple files, so files need to be numbered.

  ```
  #include <windows.h>
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <tchar.h>
  #include <psapi.h>
  #include <dirent.h>
  #include <iostream>
  #include <string>

  #pragma comment( lib, "psapi.lib" )
  using namespace std;

  void PrintProcessNameAndID( DWORD processID ) // Get a list of all running processes
  {
      TCHAR szProcessName[MAX_PATH] = TEXT("<unknown>");

      HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess( PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION |
                             PROCESS_VM_READ,
                             FALSE, processID );

  if (NULL != hProcess )
  {
      HMODULE hMod;
      DWORD cbNeeded;

  if ( EnumProcessModules( hProcess, &hMod, sizeof(hMod), 
       &cbNeeded) )
  {
      GetModuleBaseName( hProcess, hMod, szProcessName, 
                         sizeof(szProcessName)/sizeof(TCHAR) );
  }
  }
  _tprintf( TEXT("%s  (PID: %u)\n"), szProcessName, processID );
  CloseHandle( hProcess );
  }

  int main( void )
  {
      DWORD aProcesses[1024], cbNeeded, cProcesses;
      unsigned int i;

  if ( !EnumProcesses( aProcesses, sizeof(aProcesses), &cbNeeded ) )
      return 1;

  cProcesses = cbNeeded / sizeof(DWORD);
  cout<<"\n\n";
  cout<<"Get a list of all running processes\n\n";
  for ( i = 0; i < cProcesses; i++ )
  {
      if( aProcesses[i] != 0 )
      {
          PrintProcessNameAndID( aProcesses[i] );
      }
  }

  /*Get the list of all the directories in the root folder of C++ */

  cout<<"\n\n";
  cout<<"Get the list of all the directories in the root folder of C++ (not recursive)\n\n";

  DIR *dirStr = NULL;
  string FilePath;

  cout<<"Enter C++ root directory path: "; cin>>FilePath;
  dirStr = opendir(FilePath.c_str());
  dirent *nextFile = NULL;

  while ((nextFile = readdir(dirStr))!=NULL)
  {
      if (nextFile->d_name[0] != '.')
          cout<<nextFile->d_name<<endl;
  }
  return 0;
  }
  ```

How can I send the list of processes and directories using sockets to a remote server and how will I be able to write those info to a file using PHP ?

I've searched here on so many questions related to:

- **sending c++ parameters using sockets**
- **store c++ parameters in php files**

But none helped me out. Any ideas ?

Comment: in general, you will need to serialize your objects on the sender side, and deserialize them correspondingly on the receiver side.